# Перегрузка оператора через метод или через функцию

Tags: c++, ооп

Код реализован в пределах одного .cpp файла:

```
class Foo
{
  public:
    int m_a;
    Foo(int num) : m_a(num){}
    Foo operator+(const Foo& f);
    {
        return m_a + f1.m_a;
    }
};

   Foo operator+(const Foo& f1, const Foo& f2)
    {
        return f1.m_a + f2.m_a;
    }
```

Почему вызывается перегрузка оператора через метод и не возникает неопределенность вызова?

Comment: Уберите `;` после `Foo operator+(const Foo& f);`. И что такое `f1` внутри метода класса?

Comment: "Почему вызывается перегрузка оператора через метод..." - это неверно. Какая перегрузка будет вызываться - зависит от параметров.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Неопределенность вызова не возникает потому, что перегрузка через метод не объявлена как `const`. В результате ваша перегрузка через метод реализует перегрузку бинарного оператора `+` для параметров

```
не-const + const
```

А перегрузка отдельной функцией реализует перегрузку бинарного оператора `+` для параметров

```
const + const
```

Вот это различие в константности первого аргумента и позволяет компилятору избежать неоднозначности при выборе метода. Например

```
int main()
{
  Foo a(0), b(0);
  a + b; // Вызывается перегрузка методом класса

  const Foo ca(0), cb(0);
  ca + cb; // Вызывается перегрузка отдельной функцией
}
```

Если вы добавите в объявление вашего метода `const`

```
Foo operator+(const Foo& f) const
{
    return m_a + f.m_a;
}
```

то обе перегрузки сразу же станут полностью эквивалентными и компилятор начнет ругаться на неоднозначность при попытке использования оператора.